# Recursion - Inserting a temp value to a sorted array

Tags: arrays, sorting, recursion

I have a recursion function `insert` which takes a sorted array and a temp value and appends the temp value to the right place.

Example:

arr = [1,3,5,7]

temp = 2

arr should be changed to [1,2,3,5,7]. However, it doesn't append the value 2 in the right place.

```
def insert(arr,temp):
if len(arr) == 0 or arr[len(arr)-1] <= temp or arr == []:
    arr.append(temp)
    return
val = arr[len(arr)-1]
arr = arr[:len(arr)-1]
insert(arr,temp)
arr.append(val)
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing return values, so that when you call your function, no value is actually retrieved from it.

```
def insert(arr,temp):
    if len(arr) == 0 or arr[len(arr)-1] <= temp:
        arr.append(temp)
        return arr
    val = arr[len(arr)-1]
    arr = arr[:len(arr)-1]
    arr = insert(arr,temp)
    arr.append(val)
    return arr
```

This should fix it.